# URL redirect in IIS on windows server 2012 not working properly

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, webserver, url-routing

We have recently started using MVC which has modified the way we browser to our site in IIS.

We currently have a website address like this:

```
http://myserver.mydomain:123/
```

What we need is to redirect to this site:

```
http://myserver.mydomain:123/web
```

This needs to work for all pages in our site (i.e /web/login.aspx /web/workflow.aspx etc.)

This is what I have currently setup our configuration in our web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*123" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/web" />

        </rule>

    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This does not work for all occurrences.. Please help

I even tried this and still no luck..

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test">
                <match url="^https://localhost:3443/$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="web/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fweb" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Common mistake #1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 The `url` in `match` tag is completely wrong.

Comment: That didn't help me, I have posted the updated version of my rewrite rule. Please advise how to fix.